# parameters for mapreduce

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

I am using Java mapreduce module of appengine
I get the following info message

Out of mapper quota. Aborting request until quota is replenished. Consider increasing mapreduce.mapper.inputprocessingrate (default 1000) if you would like your mapper job to complete faster.

Task parameters.
queue name = default
rate = 1/s
bucketsize = 1

I have about 2000 entities of the KIND, and I am just doing the logging in the map() call

What mapreduce/task parameters needs to be provided to get rid of that info message.

-Aswath

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is a special quota in mapreduce implemented by the framework itself. It's designed to limit the speed that it can consume resources, so that 
mapreduce does not run through available app engine quota too quickly. It looks like it denotes the maximum overall rate of map() calls/second.

Try increasing the `mapreduce.mapper.inputprocessingrate` property in the configuration for your map job.
Or, just to test, you can change the default, defined in `mapreduce/AppEngineJobContext.java`:

```
public static final int DEFAULT_MAP_INPUT_PROCESSING_RATE = 1000;
```